# where to find files downloaded from react native app in iOS device

Tags: react-native

I am using rn-fetch-blob package to download files with any file to my device from an api call.  I gave specific download path if the app is being used in android. If the app is being used in iOS, I specified the path as RNfetchblob.dirs.DocumentsDir+/filename/. The downloaded files can be viewed in file manager in android. But in iOS, as there is no concept of file manager, where should I be able to view the downloaded files. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you cannot directly view a file, as there's no official file manager letting you do such a thing.

If you have downloaded something like an image, you can still access it and use them in your components.

For example, an image using the rnfetchBlob file would be:

```
 <Image source {{Platform.OS === 'ios'?RNfetchblob.dirs.DocumentsDir + /filename + '.' + extension:
   "file://"+ RNfetchblob.dirs.DocumentsDir + /filename + '.' + extension}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But, what if the downloaded file is of type other than image(i.e., pdf, mp3, mp4, etc)

Comment: It's the same for video files, and I think it's the same with other files, so It shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Hey @Auticcat can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60459901/download-audio-file-in-react-native) question, please?

Comment: @Auticcat Then How Google chrome in Ios Downloads files to the public Directory ??