# Download Audio file in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, rn-fetch-blob

I'm trying to download audio file "mp3" using `rn-fetch-blob`.

So I have more than one cases :)

When I trying to add a path to RNFetchBlob config like this

```
const pathFile = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.MainBundleDir // Or .DocumentDir // Others is crashed my App 'Android';
```

The callback "then" get success so it's Log

> `The file is saved to 
>   /data/user/0/com.music/files/RNFetchBlobTmp_1ueoigyb8hoscuuizzsue.mp3`

But when I try to explore this file in my real device I can't find them I don't know why!

So there's one faced same issue like this in Android?

```
startDownload = () => {
    const {url} = this.state;
    const pathFile = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir;
    let date = new Date();
    RNFetchBlob.config({
      fileCache: true,
      path:
        pathFile +
        '/me_' +
        Math.floor(date.getTime() + date.getSeconds() / 2),
    })
      .fetch('GET', url)
      .then(res => {
        console.log('The file is save to ', res.path()); // It's log here but i can't see the file :\
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('err', err));
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this issue by request for permission firstly then call the download function,

But actually I don't know why they tell me the file downloaded firstly before asking for permission :\

So

```
requestToPermissions = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        {
          title: 'Music',
          message:
            'App needs access to your Files... ',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        },
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log('startDownload...');
        this.startDownload();
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };


startDownload = () => {
    const {tunes, token, currentTrackIndex} = this.state;
    let {url, name} = tunes[currentTrackIndex];
    RNFetchBlob.config({
      fileCache: true,
      appendExt: 'mp3',
      addAndroidDownloads: {
        useDownloadManager: true,
        notification: true,
        title: name,
        path: RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir + `${name}`, // Android platform
        description: 'Downloading the file',
      },
    })
      .fetch('GET', url)
      .then(res => {
        console.log('res', res);
        console.log('The file is save to ', res.path());
      });
  };
```